# how to read and write message to Oracle MQ from webservice?

Tags: web-services, oracle, mq

I have rceived a request that i need to communicate ti Oracle MQ through webservices. because i have other application will interact with webservice to post data to oracle MQ. because this applications is not MQ implemented app. In this how do i need to read and write data into MQ using webservice? What are the techniques are there to monitor whether the message arrived in Queue and make webservice to read it? Please guide me. i am more confused.i am new to this blindly.

this webservice application will be hosted in the demandware application. the webservice application reads the message in the Oracle MQ which is in the form of Xml file and places into the other Message queue which is also in the form of xml. Demandware application periodically invokes the request to webservice to get/ put the message from MQ queue.

Comment: The post says Oracle MQ but doesn't mention WebSphere. The tags say WebSphere but don't mention Oracle. Can you clarify what it is you are trying to do and on which components?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is coming late, but still.

Demandware is not suitable for general purpose development, especially when proprietary protocols are involved.
My suggestion would be to use middleware component in cases like this.